# What would the advantage of a piercable butane canister be?

Tags: canister-stoves

All of the butane gas cartridges I have seen have a screwable top for attaching your stove, however, there are apparently also pierceable cartridges without a screwable top.

[image]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quite_powerful_petard_for_campfire.JPG)

What would the advantage of this type of canister be or is this style just not seen in the U.S? (I went looking yesterday and the only ones I could find were screwable tops)

Comment: Cheaper perhaps?

Comment: @TomasBy I think so, to be honest I have never seen this style of canister and I suspect it might be a European thing but I really don't know

Comment: @TomasBy Not that brand but similiar ones, these would be pretty standard https://www.google.com/shopping/product/351872325869933353?q=campingaz+canisters&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS810US810&biw=1920&bih=969&prds=local:1,paur:ClkAsKraXy9oWMCsOKes6UsC-PTew-PA-IS0snrJMKUXEij-iTy1IbUeGzVZbI7LUq8vWQcQNE8HELmiYQzFstec339uXXSmo5HHb0OKFEfDu5c2mER54ZK4JRIZAFPVH72itIDPwgIjbRq4Y2KyV5r6zW4aZg,prmr:2&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivi_qAyLfiAhUxgK0KHTALAKoQ8wII1QI

Comment: Campingaz is a French brand but almost universally available in Europe, they're one of the better options to use for that reason.

Comment: Have you actually **found** those canisters for sale somewhere? We sold them where I worked in the past but it stopped being carried around 2010. I thought it was just a legacy product for people with older stoves that finally was discontinued for the safer, more modern safety valve canisters (similar to OPD valves on BBQ tanks). That's in North America as opposed to Europe where Camping Gaz seems to still manufacture the valve-less cans.

Answer (score 7):

In UK I have only ever used the simple type. The female part of the screw thread is on the shroud which clamps around the gas cartridge, and the appliance screws into that, instead of the canister. So there is only one screw thread to manufacture for the re-usable shroud, instead of every cartridge.

[image]

Apart from the trade-off between the cost of the shroud and the cost of cartridges, an advantage is that appliances that use these cartridges don't need to match any thread size.

Answer (score 6):

The advantage of the "one way"/piercable canisters is that they are way cheaper (up to four times with respect to price per mass of gas according to German Wikipedia). Also they are "good enough" for many purposes, I.e. when you can leave the stove or burner attached for the lifetime of the canister.

Comment: They're also quite versatile. I have a blowtorch that uses that cylinder (in fact I don't currently have a stove or lantern that does, partly because the need to keep the cylinder attached is a pain).